# computing onset date of snowmelt in R

Tags: r, dplyr, threshold

I have daily temperature in this format starting from 1950 to 2017
[Data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tsi8vd1f7mgzujx/temp.xlsx?dl=0)

I need to compute snowmelt onset date  *which is defined as as the the first day when daily temperature is above 0 C, following the last five-day period between March and May, when the daily temperature is below 0 C.* My codes so far:

```
  df1<-read.csv("temp.csv")
  require(dplyr)
  # applying the condition to check each temperature value
  df1$boolean<- ifelse(df1$temp<0.0 , 1, 0)

  #computing the total sum < 0 and the start and end date
  snow<-df1 %>%
  mutate(boolean = ifelse(is.na(boolean), 0, boolean)) %>%
  group_by(group = cumsum(c(0, diff(boolean) != 0))) %>%
   filter(boolean == 1 & n() > 1) %>%
   summarize("Start Date"=min(as.character(date)),
        "End Date"=max(as.character(date)),
        "Length of Run"=n()) %>%
   ungroup() %>%
  select(-matches("group"))
colnames(snow)[3] <- 'length'

# subset length that greater >5
obs<-subset(snow,length >=5)
```

The codes above give me partial solution ( if  further manually edit I will get ideal solution to match my definition) I am only interested in one onset date for each year. I need some further guidance on how I can edit this code  to compute onset date based on definition above.

I have number of locations so manually editing this would not be ideal solution.
Your help would be appreciated

Comment: A bit more data that actually contain the case you are looking for would be helpful

Comment: Please read [How to Create a Complete, Minimal, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update your post. We specifically need to have you post enough data so we can figure out how to calculate the snowmelt onset date.

Comment: i added a subset of the data

Comment: Could you be more specific on corner cases? Like if there is no five day below 0 period in March and May?

Comment: because of the location, i anticipate that i will get my last five day to occur in March or  April or May. hence not too worried about that

Comment: Must the melt onset date be between Mar and May or is that just a restriction on the 5 consecutive subzero temperature days and the melt onset date could be in June, say?

Comment: What about 1959? The onset seems to be on 1959-06-02, which does not fall to your criteria - so there is no onset for that year?

Comment: This question needs a small subset of the data sufficient to illustrate the problem right in the question so that it survives removal of the dropbox data.  See [mcve] and note the *minimal* part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have assumed in (1) that the melt day must occur in Mar, Apr or May and in (2) that only the 5 subzero days occur in Mar, Apr, May but the melt day could occur in June, say.

**1)** Define df2 which is df1 plus additional columns: month, year and code where code is 0 if the date is not in Mar, Apr, May and is otherwise 1 if temp < 0 and 2 if temp >= 0.

Now using `df2` run `rollapplyr` on code returning TRUE if the most recent 6 dates have codes 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2 and otherwise FALSE.  Take the TRUE rows and only keep the last in each year.  Right join that to a data frame of all years in order to generate NAs in the output for any missing years.

```
library(zoo)

df2 <- df1 %>%
    mutate(Date = as.Date(Date), month = as.numeric(format(Date, "%m")), 
           year = as.numeric(format(Date, "%Y")),
           code = (month %in% 3:5) * ((temp < 0) + 2 * (temp >= 0)),
           OK = rollapplyr(code, 6, identical, c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2), fill = FALSE))

df2 %>%
       filter(OK) %>%
       filter(!duplicated(year, fromLast = TRUE)) %>%
       right_join(unique(df2["year"]), by = "year") %>%
       select(year, Date)
```

giving:

```
   year       Date
1  1950 1950-05-24
2  1951 1951-05-21
3  1952 1952-05-28
4  1953 1953-05-15
5  1954 1954-05-28
6  1955 1955-05-14
7  1956 1956-05-27
8  1957 1957-05-17
9  1958 1958-05-21
10 1959       <NA>
11 1960 1960-05-26
12 1961 1961-05-16
13 1962 1962-05-19
14 1963 1963-05-13
15 1964 1964-05-27
16 1965 1965-05-20
17 1966 1966-05-26
18 1967 1967-05-26
19 1968 1968-05-27
20 1969 1969-05-30
21 1970 1970-05-21
```

**2)**  In (1) we assumed that the melt onset day must be in Mar, Apr or May but here we assume that only the subzero days lie in that range and the melt onset day may extend further out.

Calculations are the same as in (1) except that the codes are now such that 1 indicates a subzero temperature in Mar, Apr or May, 2 indicates any temp above zero any time (not just in Mar, Apr and May) and 0 is anything else.  We collapse the codes into a character string (one character per date) and use a regular expression on it to look for a substring of 5 ones followed by anything until we get to the next 2.  We process the rest as in (1) except now we don't need the join since there will always be a melt onset day.   Without the join we can represent this now as a single pipeline.

```
df1 %>%
    mutate(Date = as.Date(Date), month = as.numeric(format(Date, "%m")), 
           year = as.numeric(format(Date, "%Y")),
           code = (month %in% 3:5) * (temp < 0) + 2 * (temp >= 0),
           OK = { g <- gregexpr("1{5}.*?2", paste(code, collapse = ""))[[1]]
                  seq_along(code) %in% (g + attr(g, "match.length") - 1) }) %>%
    filter(OK) %>%
    filter(!duplicated(year, fromLast = TRUE)) %>%
    select(year, Date)
```

giving:

```
   year       Date
1  1950 1950-05-24
2  1951 1951-06-01
3  1952 1952-05-28
4  1953 1953-05-15
5  1954 1954-05-28
6  1955 1955-05-14
7  1956 1956-05-27
8  1957 1957-05-17
9  1958 1958-05-21
10 1959 1959-06-02
11 1960 1960-05-26
12 1961 1961-05-16
13 1962 1962-05-19
14 1963 1963-06-01
15 1964 1964-05-27
16 1965 1965-05-20
17 1966 1966-05-26
18 1967 1967-05-26
19 1968 1968-05-27
20 1969 1969-05-30
21 1970 1970-05-21
```

Comment: I learned a lot from your answer today. I just want to confirm that `c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2)` is an optional argument for identical, and each 6 elements in code is checked with the optional argument in identical. Is that right?

Comment: It's the same as `rollapplyr(codes, 6, function(x) identical(x, c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2), fill = FALSE)`.  That is the first arg to `identical` is the window on `codes` and the second is c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2)`.

Comment: Thank you very much for that explanation. The code let me confirm what I was wondering.

Comment: Have added (2) which changes the assumption in (1) so that the melt onset day may occur further out.

Comment: thank you! 2) works fine for my needs!

Answer (score 2):

A straightforward solution in `tidyverse`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)


readxl::read_excel("temp.xlsx") -> df1

df1 %>%
  mutate(year = year(Date),
         month = month(Date)) %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  mutate(
    below_0 = as.numeric(temp < 0),
    streak5 = cumsum(below_0) - cumsum(lag(below_0, 5, 0)),
    onset = month %in% c(3, 4, 5) & lag(streak5) == 5 & below_0 == 0) %>% 
  filter(onset) %>%
  summarise(Date = last(Date))
```

Gives

```
# A tibble: 20 x 2
    year       Date
   <dbl>     <dttm>
 1  1950 1950-05-24
 2  1951 1951-05-21
 3  1952 1952-05-28
 4  1953 1953-05-15
 5  1954 1954-05-28
 6  1955 1955-05-14
 7  1956 1956-05-27
 8  1957 1957-05-17
 9  1958 1958-05-21
10  1960 1960-05-26
11  1961 1961-05-16
12  1962 1962-05-19
13  1963 1963-05-13
14  1964 1964-05-27
15  1965 1965-05-20
16  1966 1966-05-26
17  1967 1967-05-26
18  1968 1968-05-27
19  1969 1969-05-30
20  1970 1970-05-21
```

I hope the code more or less explains itself, `streak5` is the number of previous days with temp below 0, `onset` implements the criteria given in the question, `summarise` picks the last date in given year.

Answer (score 1):

`rle()` to the rescue!

```
library(broom)
library(tidyverse)

temp <- read_csv("temp.csv")
```

Best read the pipe below first before reading this helper function.

For each year we:

- take a run-length encoding of above/below 0
- the first one that's TRUE (<0) and has 5+ consecutive days is our candidate
- take the next index
- if that's too much (no days that fit the criteria) return NA
- else return that date

thus:

```
mk_runs <- function(xdf) {

  r <- rle(xdf$below_0) take the T/F RLE
  pos <- which(r$values & r$length>=5)[1] # find the first one meeting criteria
  idx <- (sum(r$lengths[1:pos]))+1 # sum the lengths up until this point and add 1 to get to the first > 0 day

  if (idx > nrow(xdf)) { # if past our date range return NA
    data_frame(year=xdf$year[1], date=NA)
  } else {
    xdf[idx, c("year", "date")]
  }

}
```

We need to get the data into shape:

```
separate(temp, Date, c("month", "day", "year")) %>%
  mutate_all(as.numeric) %>% 
  mutate(year = ifelse(year >=50, 1900+year, 2000+year)) %>% 
  mutate(date = as.Date(sprintf("%04d-%02d-%02d", year, month, day))) %>% 
  mutate(month = lubridate::month(date)) %>% 
  mutate(below_0 = temp < 0) %>% 
  filter(month >= 3 & month <=5) %>% 
  group_by(year) %>% # year groups
  arrange(date) %>%  # in order
  do(mk_runs(.)) %>% # see above function
  print(n=21)
## # A tibble: 21 x 2
## # Groups:   year [21]
##     year       date
##    <dbl>     <date>
##  1  1950 1950-04-30
##  2  1951 1951-05-21
##  3  1952 1952-05-28
##  4  1953 1953-05-15
##  5  1954 1954-05-28
##  6  1955 1955-05-14
##  7  1956 1956-05-02
##  8  1957 1957-05-07
##  9  1958 1958-04-27
## 10  1959         NA
## 11  1960 1960-04-24
## 12  1961 1961-05-16
## 13  1962 1962-05-19
## 14  1963 1963-05-13
## 15  1964 1964-05-20
## 16  1965 1965-05-20
## 17  1966 1966-05-07
## 18  1967 1967-04-27
## 19  1968 1968-05-10
## 20  1969 1969-05-22
## 21  1970 1970-05-21
```

Comment: I could not handle all using tidyverse ways. Plus one for your tidy solution.

Comment: I'm afraid the results are not correct (eg 1950).

Answer (score 0):

Here is another attempt. In my first step, I created two new columns first (i.e., year and month). Then, I filtered the data for data between March and May. Then, I created index numbers for rows which have temperature higher than 0 Celsius. This process is done per year. Since you need to have five consecutive days before those days that have temperature above zero, index numbers equal to / smaller than 5 needs to be ignored. This is done `if_else()` in the true condition in the outer `if_else()`.

In my second step, I chose to use a package called `SOfun` which is developed by the author of `splitstackshape`. You can download this package from github. What `getMyRows()` is doing are; 1) it identifies which rows should be considered by specifying `pattern`, 2) get a certain range of rows from the marked rows in 1), and 3) create a list. Here `range = -5:0` means that I am choosing five previous rows of a target row, and the target row itself.

In my third step, I subsetted `mylist` with two logical conditions. `!is.na(x$ind[6])` checks if the 6th element of `ind` is not NA, and `all(x$temp[1:5] < 0)` checks if the 1st-5th elements of temp (temperature) are all smaller than zero. `Filter()` chooses list elements that satisfy the two logical condition. Then, I extracted the 6th row from each data frame since that is the target row. I bound the list, grouped the data by year and chose the first observation for each year using `slice()`.

```
library(devtools)

install_github("mrdwab/overflow-mrdwab")
install_github("mrdwab/SOfun")

library(overflow)
library(SOfun)
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)

# Part 1
mydf <- read_excel("temp.xlsx") %>%
        mutate(year = as.numeric(format(Date, "%Y")),
               month = as.numeric(format(Date, "%m"))) %>%
        filter(between(month, 3, 5)) %>%
        group_by(year) %>%
        mutate(ind = if_else(temp > 0, 
                     {ind <- row_number()
                      if_else(ind <= 5, NA_integer_, ind)},
                      NA_integer_)) %>%
        ungroup

# Part 2
mylist <- getMyRows(mydf,
                    pattern = which(complete.cases(mydf$ind)),
                    range = -5:0, isNumeric = TRUE)

# Part 3
Filter(function(x) !is.na(x$ind[6]) & all(x$temp[1:5] < 0), mylist) %>%
lapply(function(x) x[6, ]) %>%
bind_rows %>%
group_by(year) %>%
slice(1) %>%
select(Date)

    year Date               
   <dbl> <dttm>             
 1  1950 1950-04-30 00:00:00
 2  1951 1951-05-21 00:00:00
 3  1952 1952-05-28 00:00:00
 4  1953 1953-05-15 00:00:00
 5  1954 1954-05-28 00:00:00
 6  1955 1955-05-14 00:00:00
 7  1956 1956-05-02 00:00:00
 8  1957 1957-05-07 00:00:00
 9  1958 1958-04-27 00:00:00
10  1960 1960-04-24 00:00:00
11  1961 1961-05-16 00:00:00
12  1962 1962-05-19 00:00:00
13  1963 1963-05-13 00:00:00
14  1964 1964-05-20 00:00:00
15  1965 1965-05-20 00:00:00
16  1966 1966-05-07 00:00:00
17  1967 1967-04-27 00:00:00
18  1968 1968-05-10 00:00:00
19  1969 1969-05-22 00:00:00
20  1970 1970-05-21 00:00:00
```

Comment: I'm afraid the results are not correct (eg 1950).

Comment: @liborm Thanks for your comment. I checked the data. On the 30th of April, 1950, temperature was 1.50. Five previous consecutive days have temperature below zero. This date is the first date that temperature stayed above zero between March and May in 1950. Can you confirm that with your data?

Comment: @liborm `the first day when daily temperature is above 0 C, following the last five-day period between March and May, when the daily temperature is below 0 C` seems to indicate the first day that temperature is above zero and temperature of the previous five consecutive days is below zero.  If this interpretation is not right, I think the OP needs to clearify this definition.

Comment: @liborm I see. I think what we intuitively think may not be reflected in the data set. If so, what we want to question is the reliability of the data set, rather than judging what outcome is right or not right.

Comment: heh .. i'm sorry, I reacted in a hurry and thought i'm in the thread below the question. The problem with your solution is straightforward and has nothing to do with 1959 - OP asks for `following the last five-day period`. You failed to identify the last period in 1950, you just found a five day period.